# Сильно загружает сервер Mysql

Tags: mysql, debian

У меня почему то сильно виснет mysql на сервере. запустил команду `htop` и получил такую картину - [скрин](http://joxi.ru/4Akqw1bSoQQ65m)

Посмотрел `show processlist` - нету зависших процесов - [скрин](http://joxi.ru/KAxLRQOHZ337DA)

Помогите понять, почему такое происходит.

ОС - Debian 8

Comment: Первое, что я бы посмотрел, это наличие и состояние подключений и выполнение тяжёлых операций.

Comment: можете подсказать как это посмотреть?

Comment: Есть специальные утилиты для этого. Тот же MySqlWorkbench или в консоли   `show processlist`. Дальше, как говорится по обстоятельствам.

Comment: так я писал, что процессов нету

Comment: пробовал много времени бороться, но ничего не помогает. http://joxi.ru/KAgq9npSXNxRnm - картина осталась прежней